# What is the max allowed depth for bip32 derivation paths?

Tags: wallet

Generally I see that bip32 derivation paths are something like m/1/2/3/4, etc

How deep is allowed? Is there a limit on how deep the tree can go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A path can have, at most, 256 elements, including the master. This limitation comes from the [extended public key serialization](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#serialization-format) format's depth field. This field is a single  byte which means it only has 256 possible values.

Comment: I dont get it. What happens if I try to get 'm/44/0/0/666' address?

Comment: Nothing happens, that's a valid path. Depth is the number of elements; basically the number of `/`'s. The actual value of each element can be a at most `2^31 - 1`.